# React Hook's state not getting updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've built a React Hook as follows:

```
const Index = (props) => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPosts = async () => {
      const posts = await getPostFromWebService()
      for (let i of posts) {
        setPosts([ ...posts, i ])
      }
    }

    getPosts()
  }, [])

  // ... remaining code
}
```

But even if the web service returns 5 posts, only the last posts is getting updated in the `posts` state. Hence it only receives one post in it, instead of 5.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: maybe try to remove for loop and call something like `setPosts(posts)`?

Comment: It feels like a performance issue to call setPosts for each post.

Comment: @akkonrad: That may work but what about a case where I would fetch 5 more posts, just like pagination, and I wanted to append those to the existing posts?

Comment: this code seems incomplete, but I would call something like this then: `setPosts([...oldPosts, ...fetchedPosts])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like this. Here we would have the useEffect listen for any changes in postCount so that we can trigger your logic to fetch more posts.

```
const Index = (props) => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
  const [postCount, setPostCount] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPosts = async () => {
      const newPosts= await getPostFromWebService()

      setPosts([...posts, newPosts])
    }
  }, [postCount])

  return(
    <div>
       <button onClick={() => setPostCount(postCount + 5)}>Get more posts</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```